# How to use regex to match equalty of two variables?

Tags: regex

I have lines formed like this:

```
1/1
3/5
5/5
7/10
```

Is there a way to match lines in which the number on the left matches the number on the right?

That is, I would need to match lines 1/1 and 5/5.

Comment: Why not just `split` the string and test for equality? Use the right tool for the right job.

Comment: I didn't provide the context. Why did you assume I can "split"?

Comment: ....because they're strings. Prettymuch any language worth its salt should have a built-in function (or a library) to split a string.

Comment: You're asking the logical equivalent of "How do I pound this nail in with a screwdriver?" You don't. Use a hammer.

Comment: Well, I won't do split because regex is faster. I have a jQuery datatable column filter which has an option to filter out some rows based on the input in the filter. Since the filter supports regex, I'm going to use regex instead of "split".

Comment: "Well, I won't do split because regex is faster." 1. I'm not at all convinced of this (although a benchmark test would be interesting), and 2. I **sincerely** doubt that this is the performance bottleneck of whatever application you're working on. Stop prematurely optimizing.

Comment: I'm trying to learn alternative ways of doing things. Besides, I didn't mention execution speed - I referred to "doing" speed. Writing regex in my case is faster then using jQuery to split / compare.

Comment: As of this writing, this question is 12 minutes old. You're saying that it would take you at least 12 minutes to write a snippet of code in which the lines are split and the pieces compared?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a [backreference](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html#usebackrefinregex):

```
^(\d+)/\1$
```

Comment: This seems to match 0 / 10 aswell. What I'm looking for is a number match aswell.

Comment: @Tool: It does not match `0/10`. [Proof](http://rubular.com/r/OWNuQ5Mq9w). Can you provide some code to support your claim?

Comment: Seems like the spaces infront and after the slash messed it up. Thanks, I'm accepting your answer ;).

Comment: @Tool: You can allow optional whitespace before and after the slash by writing `^(\d+)\s*/\s*\1$`

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick:

```
^(\d+)/\1$
```

We match 1 or more digits in the group, then insist they also appear after the slash.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming match.txt contains your input, and you're in a bash shell,

```
cat match.txt | sed -e 's+\(.*\)/\(.*\)+if [ \1 = \2 ]; then echo \1/\2; fi+' | sh
```